# building a df from nested lists and dictionaries in a more Pythonic DRY way

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

i have a list with dictionaries in which some dictionaries have a list of dictionaries too:

```
samples = [
    {"person": "A", "employed": True, "location": "East", 
    "donations": []},
    {"person": "B", "employed": False, "location": "West", 
    "donations": [
                 {"type": "cash", "date": "july 25, 2022", "value": 50},
                 {"type": "stocks", "date": "May 1, 2022", "value": 2500}
                 ]},
    {"person": "C", "employed": False, "location": "North",
    "donations": []}
]
```

I wanted process this data to create a dataframe that has flattened the nested dictionaries and added new column headers like this:

[image]

Here's the code that I have have, but it has a lot of repetition. What is an approach to make it more Pythonic and DRY:

```
data_list = [] ## initial empty list
for sample in samples:
    ## get data that is not nested
    person = sample.get("person")
    employed = sample.get("employed")
    location = sample.get("location")
    ## if there is not nested data, give specific values
    if len(sample.get("donations")) < 1:
        donation_type = donation_date =  donation_value = "NONE LISTED"
        ## build list
        data_list.append({"person": person,
                  "employed": employed,
                  "location": location,
                  "donation_type": donation_type,
                  "donation_date": donation_date,
                  "donation_value": donation_value,
                 })
    else:
        ## build same list but with provided values
        donations = sample.get("donations")
        for donation in donations:
            data_list.append({"person": person,
                "employed": employed,
                "location": location,
                "donation_type": donation.get("type"),
                "donation_date": donation.get("date"),
                "donation_value": donation.get("value")
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for this because you don't need to supply the column names:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(samples).drop('donations', axis=1)
donations = pd.json_normalize(samples, record_path='donations', meta=['person'])
pd.merge(df, donations, how= 'left', on = 'person').apply(lambda x: x.fillna("NONE LISTED"))
```

Output:

```
person  employed    location    type    date    value
0   A   True    East    NONE LISTED NONE LISTED NONE LISTED
1   B   False   West    cash    july 25, 2022   50
2   B   False   West    stocks  May 1, 2022 2500
3   C   False   North   NONE LISTED NONE LISTED NONE LISTED
```

Comment: If there was another dict item with a list, could you have two record_path items? like record_path=['donations', 'items']

Comment: The docs state __record_path:__ _str or list of str, default None_ - so it looks like it. You may have to mess around with the syntax of the join a little - it's quite different so if you can't work it out it may be worth asking another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(samples).explode('donations')
df_out = pd.concat([
          df.drop('donations',axis=1), 
          df['donations'].apply(pd.Series).fillna('NONE LISTED')[['type', 'date', 'value']]], 
          axis=1)

#You can rename the columns after as needed.
```

print(df_out):

```
  person  employed location         type           date        value
0      A      True     East  NONE LISTED    NONE LISTED  NONE LISTED
1      B     False     West         cash  july 25, 2022         50.0
1      B     False     West       stocks    May 1, 2022       2500.0
2      C     False    North  NONE LISTED    NONE LISTED  NONE LISTED
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the solution using only [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
dummy = [{"type": "NONE LISTED", "date": "NONE LISTED", "value": "NONE LISTED"}]
for sample in samples:
    if not sample["donations"]:
        sample["donations"] = dummy
res = pd.json_normalize(samples, "donations", ["person", "employed", "location"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
          type           date        value person employed location
0  NONE LISTED    NONE LISTED  NONE LISTED      A     True     East
1         cash  july 25, 2022           50      B    False     West
2       stocks    May 1, 2022         2500      B    False     West
3  NONE LISTED    NONE LISTED  NONE LISTED      C    False    North
```